# No such file or directory when I type "cd desktop"

Tags: command-line, directory, cd-command

I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

My problem is that when I try to access my desktop or any folder at my home directory, it always gives me this error

```
No such file or directory
```

even though the folder exists and I can see it with the `ls` command

[image: Screenshot of terminal showing bash: cd: desktop: no such file or directory]

Comment: Capitalization matters. Try `cd Desktop`.

Comment: ...and as a bonus: *never* do things in your home directory as root (as shown in the screenshot). Very easy to mess thing up and be unable to login again...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The path names are case sensitive.

Therefore, it should be

```
cd Desktop
```

instead of

```
cd desktop
```

Comment: ah i didn't realize it, shame on me --
Thank you :)